# Entity framework, repository/service with ability to read/write at same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Lets take simple repository ( or service, or manager or whatever you usually call it ) :

```
public class Repository
{
    Context context = new Context();

    public void Add()
    {
        context.Products.Add(new Product());
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void AddEvent()
    {
        context.Events.Add(new Event());
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return context.products;
    }
}

public class TheClass
{
    public void Run()
    {
        foreach (var product in Repository.GetAll())
            Repository.AddEvent();
    }
}
```

Execute Run() and we'll get exception 3988. We can't run through read loop and flush changes at same time. Ok.
But at same time in huge project its not so clear when we need to save or not after loop ends ( cross-calls, API calls, possible exceptions, multiple threads, bad luck and so on .. ) So im looking for some "best practice" to organize this classes in same way and make them safe without getting logic out of them.

For now i've figured out few solutions :

**1. Chunks.** 
Pros : Looks fine in code, could be part of query.
Cons : Multiple SQL transactions. In huge query it could be pain in performance. Cursor position will fail ( no more paging :) )

**2. .ToList()**
Pros : ?
Cons : Not applicable to huge data, performance.

**3. Use different transaction for save operations**
Have not tried yet. Just idea, possibly wrong way at all.

**4. ( this is what im currently using ) Create base class for managers (repositories/services) with "safe save" function**. It tries to save, if read transaction in progress = handle its exception and flag to save on dispose ( or flag could be set at creation time )

```
public abstract class DataManagerBase<T> : IDisposable where T : DbContext
{
    protected T Context;

    bool SaveOnDispose;
    public DataManagerBase(bool saveOnDispose = false)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(DbContext)))
            throw new Exception("Wrong class in dbcontext");
        Context = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        if (!SaveOnDispose)
        {
            try
            {
                return Context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (SqlException e) when (e.Number == 3988)
            {
                SaveOnDispose = true;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            if (SaveOnDispose && Context != null)
                try
                {
                    Context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }

            Context.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("The world has fall apart ...");
        }
    }
}
```

Pros : It works.
Cons : Cant handle errors during save ( if save will be at dispose ) -> cant make rollback ( making callbacks not seems fine for performance ), not guaranteed changes tracking during context lifetime.

**5. Create different contexts for read/write operations**
Cons : No changes tracking at all.

**6. Create new context for each operation** like this :

```
public void Add()
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            context.Products.Add(new Product());
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void AddEvent()
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            context.Events.Add(new Events());
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            return context.products;
        }
    }
```

Cons : Too many contexts :) Could be problematic in complex process mabye.

Do i miss something?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: When you do a foreach, it would have called the database at that point, so the save should be independent.  What exception are you getting, exactly?

Comment: yep, it should be independent. Im looking for best solution ( simple, clear, performance friendly, with ability to handle save errors ) in mind that same classes are used in MVC6, API and windows services (shared logic layer library).

Comment: `Repository.GetAll()` <= Do your modifications in the loop but do not call save changes until after you break out of the loop. This is because the connection is needed while you are iterating over the records. The other options is a ToList/ToArray/AsEnumerable which materialize the list.  If you think you have too many records for that then you should not be iterating over them to begin with because that is doing the exact same thing (only 1 by 1 instead of all at once) so the problem there would be bad business logic.

Comment: Doing processes with "huge data" in one context doesn't make sense anyway: the context's cache will grow until it gets unacceptably slow. Also, nesting these read and write processes only makes sense if you need the read data in the writing process. If that's true, the write process depends on external state which should always be avoided. In short, this all indicates a couple of poor design decisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You dont need seperate `context` for Read and write.

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
{
    return context.products;
}
```

> The IQueryable interface inherits the IEnumerable interface so that if
>   it represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated.
>   Enumeration causes the expression tree associated with an IQueryable
>   object to be executed

So that you need to execute it.

```
//Approach 1
public void Run()
{
    var products = Repository.GetAll().ToList();
    foreach (var product in products)
        Repository.AddEvent();
}

//Having condition in IQuerable
public void Run()
{
    var products = Repository
                  .GetAll();
                  .Where(someCondition)
                  .OrderBy(SomeOrder)
                  .ToList(); //At this point ef will materialize the query 
                  //and process in sql and you will get the 
                  //result applying this condition at SQL.
    foreach (var product in products)
        Repository.AddEvent();
}
```

Pros
 
 - It will NOT have multiple roundtrip to database 
 - It will fetch data in single shot

Cons
 
 - It will fetch data to memory

Anyway if you iterate you will load that in to the memory, So its better to avoid expensive I/O operation.

You have to close the reader associated with the connection before starting a new transaction.[msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bill/2006/06/12/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-3988/)

Keep in mind `EntityFramework Context` is not thread-safe

Comment: Thats what im wrote at 2... 
Some tables contains more than 50 000 000 records and they grow. Some tables contains complex records. So there is no way to use .ToList()
Also i cant forecast growth and complexity in future.

Comment: If you have this line  `foreach (var product in Repository.GetAll())` it will also bring the full records to memory

Comment: You can try to group your big list record into sublist and savechanges using different thread, you just need to manage concurrent access into database for reading. I think using this way you can write & read at the same time

Comment: @Eldho, guess you right. After all i can read huge record sets by parts or taking only necessary columns from them. Never checked that foreach takes all recodrs to memory, thanks. :)

Comment: Glad  it helped if you want to project columns try `Repo.GetAll().Select(x=> new { col1,col2})`;